# Смысл CSRF Token`а

Tags: веб-программирование, token, csrf

Доброго времени суток!

Изучаю csrf и не могу понять одну вещь, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
На сайте learn.javascript есть [статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/csrf) по этому поводу. Там сказано:

> Типичный способ защиты сайтов – это «секретный ключ» (secret),
>   специальное значение, которое генерируется случайным образом и
>   сохраняется в сессии посетителя. Его знает только сервер, посетителю
>   мы его даже не будем показывать.
>
> Затем на основе ключа генерируется «токен» (token). Токен делается
>   так, чтобы с одной стороны он был отличен от ключа, в частности, может
>   быть много токенов для одного ключа, с другой – чтобы было легко
>   проверить по токену, сгенерирован ли он на основе данного ключа или
>   нет.
>
> Для каждого токена нужно дополнительное случайное значение, которое
>   называют «соль» salt.
>
> Формула вычисления токена:
>
> token = salt + ":" + MD5(salt + ":" + secret) Например:
>
> В сессии хранится secret="abcdef", это значение создаётся один раз.
>   Для нового токена сгенерируем salt, например пусть salt="1234". token
>   = "1234" + ":" + MD5("1234" + ":" + "abcdef") = "1234:5ad02792a3285252e524ccadeeda3401". Это значение – с одной
>   стороны, случайное, с другой – имея такой token, мы можем взять его
>   первую часть 1234 в качестве salt и, зная secret, проверить по
>   формуле, верно ли он вычислен.
>
> Не зная secret, невозможно сгенерировать token, который сервер
>   воспримет как правильный.
>
> Далее, токен добавляется в качестве скрытого поля к каждой форме,
>   генерируемой на сервере.При её отправке сервер проверит поле csrf,
>   удостоверится в правильности токена, и лишь после этого отошлёт
>   сообщение.
>
> «Злая страница» при всём желании не сможет сгенерировать подобную
>   форму, так как не владеет secret, и токен будет неверным.

Мне непонятно вот что:

1. secret хранится в сессии, а сессия хранится в куках на клиентской машине, и каждый раз отправляется веб серверу. Разве хакер не сможет получить доступ к кукам? К ним вообще можно же получить доступ? Они хранятся же в файле где-то?
2. Если токен приходит каждый раз с формой, разве хакер не сможет этот токен из html который пришел выдрать, заюзать его и отправить для своего запроса?
3. Я так понимаю смысл всей этой ерунды есть только тогда, когда либо

   - Сайт разрешает кросс-доменные запросы от всех Origin: *
     либо
   - Злоумышленник мог ранее уже встроить форму на тот же сайт через XSS, чтобы оставаться в том же домене, так как во всех остальных случаях у нас есть CORS, зачем нам CSRF?
4. Не понял, почему формула токена именно такая:

   ```
   token = "1234" + ":" + MD5("1234" + ":" + "abcdef") = "1234:5ad02792a3285252e524ccadeeda3401"
   ```

   Зачем нужно соль "1234" склеивать со сгенерированной md5-функцией строкой? Ведь соль 1234 становится явно видна в токене!
5. Т.е. получается бразузер шлет каждый раз "abcdef" в куках как Id-сесии, и также шлет токен. Сервер еще раз генерирует токен, используя этот id сессии, и сверяет с тем, что пришел от формы? Не совсем ясно, как это помогает, если токен можно подглядеть(если можно?)

Спасибо заранее за помощь!
Отличие от [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543576/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-antiforgerytoken-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) в том, что там так и не понятно, зачем нужен CSRF если есть CORS

Comment: если у кого-то есть доступ на вашу машину, то вас мало, что спасет.

Comment: `Зачем нужно соль "1234" склеивать со сгенерированной md5-функцией строкой? Ведь соль 1234 становится явно видна в токене!` - соль видна, а secret — нет. всё норм) Хотя никто не заставляет делать именно так, как написано в learnjs. и можете токен по другому сформировать и вывести, одной строкой хэша, к примеру

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает AntiForgeryToken? Мне кажется я могу его подделать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543576/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-antiforgerytoken-%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: "...и сохраняется в сессии посетителя. Его знает только сервер, посетителю мы его даже не будем показывать." - из чего следует, что сессия хранится на сервере, а не в cookie. В cookie хранится обычно только идентификатор сессии.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman На странице с дубликатом тот же самый вопрос. Один человек ответил, что получить форму с токеном не даст SOP. Но тогда не ясен смысл, как я писал выше, зачем нужен CSRF если есть CORS?

Comment: CORS работает на стороне клиента. CSRF на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> secret хранится в сессии, а сессия хранится в куках на клиентской машине, и каждый раз отправляется веб серверу. Разве хакер не сможет получить доступ к кукам? К ним вообще можно же получить доступ? Они хранятся же в файле где-то?

Только если у него есть доступ к компьютеру пользователя. Но тогда ему вообще CSRF не нужен, т. к. есть куда более простые способы отправить запрос самому.

> Если токен приходит каждый раз с формой, разве хакер не сможет этот токен из html который пришел выдрать, заюзать его и отправить для своего запроса?

Только в случае MITM. При CSRF у хакера нет доступа к серверу, клиенту или каналу связи.

> я имею в виду разве он не может получить форму просто еще раз скриптом и этот токен потом отправить в своем запросе?

Не может - тут сработает CORS. Если запрос get, то сервер его получит, но если он не пошлёт разрешающие заголовки, то запрашивающему скрипту браузер ответ не отдаст. А на POST вообще будет OPTIONS-запрос сначала.

А если послать запрос не из браузера, а с сервера, то не будет авторизации пользователя и токен он опять же не получит.

> Я так понимаю смысл всей этой ерунды есть только тогда, когда либо
>   Сайт разрешает кросс-доменные запросы от всех Origin: * либо ...

Нет. Браузер позволит отправит форму, вот:

```
<form methog=get target="//yandex.ru">
  <input type=text name=text>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

> Не понял, почему формула токена именно такая:

Форма может быть разной.

> Зачем нужно соль "1234" склеивать со сгенерированной md5-функцией строкой? Ведь соль 1234 становится явно видна в токене!

Если соли нет, то ключ одного клиента подойдёт другому и хакер сможет использовать свой, поэтому нужна соль.

<s>Хм.. А вообще, что-то я задумался, есть тут сомнения...</s>

Разобрался: даже если хакер встроит свой валидный токен в форму, он не совпадёт с токеном в куках, поэтому форма будет отвергнута как поддельная.

> он не совпадет, потому что хакеру неизвестен id сессии, на основе котороой генерируется токен?

Я имел в виду, что у хакера может быть свой токен, который корректен для него. Но этот токен не совпадёт с тем токеном, который лежит у другого пользователя в куках. А из чужих кук он его достать не может.

> Т.е. получается бразузер шлет каждый раз "abcdef" в куках как Id-сесии, и также шлет токен. Сервер еще раз генерирует токен, используя этот id сессии, и сверяет с тем, что пришел от формы? Не совсем ясно, как это помогает, если токен можно подглядеть(если можно?)

Сайт не может залезть в чужие куки, поэтому подсмотреть нельзя.

Comment: спасибо за столь подробный ответ, скажите пожалуйста, "даже если хакер встроит свой валидный токен в форму, он не совпадёт с токеном в куках" - он не совпадет, потому что хакеру неизвестен id сессии, на основе котороой генерируется токен?

Comment: "Только в случае MITM. При CSRF у хакера нет доступа к серверу, клиенту или каналу связи" 
я имею в виду разве он не может получить форму просто еще раз скриптом и этот токен потом отправить в своем запросе?

Comment: @DaniilAndashev, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Qwerty, а на get-запросы же cors вроде не действует? Он же только для запросов, которые что-то меняют. Почему же он не сможет get`ом получить форму?

Comment: Qwerty, "Если запрос get, то сервер его получит, но если он не пошлёт разрешающие заголовки, то запрашивающему скрипту браузер ответ не отдаст". Какие разрешающие заголовки могут быть для get? Я думал, Cors на get не распространяется.

Comment: @DaniilAndashev, все те же самые. Всё действует. Просто браузер сначала пошлёт запрос, потом посмотрит в ответе заголовки, а если они подойдут, отдаст скрипту.

Comment: @Qwerty, А, всё, спасибо, я просто не много не дочитал. Получается, если мы будем пытаться получить get-ом страницу, то у нас Origin будет указан. А запрашиваемый ресурс должен запрещать все Origin, кроме своего

Comment: @Qwerty, "Я так понимаю смысл всей этой ерунды есть только тогда, когда либо Сайт разрешает кросс-доменные запросы от всех Origin: * либо ...
Нет. Браузер позволит отправит форму, вот:

<form methog=get target="//yandex.ru">
  <input type=text name=text>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>"
Но ведь тогда опять получается смысл CSRFсводится на нет. Хоть форму и можно послать, хоть можно и get-запрос сделать, но все равно будет действовать CORS - проверится origin. Зачем тогда CSRF? Или что Вы имели ввиду, "браузер позволит отправить форму"?

Comment: @DaniilAndashev, CORS не действует на формы.

Comment: Qwertiy, а, теперь ясен смысл CSRF, большое спасибо.

Comment: Qwertiy, "А на POST вообще будет OPTIONS-запрос сначала". Прочитал https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests
POST не относится к методам, для которых выполняется Preflight

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем нужно соль "1234" склеивать со сгенерированной md5-функцией строкой? Ведь соль 1234 становится явно видна в токене!

А ее и не нужно прятать. Она не для прямой секретности, а для двух других целей:

- Если результирующий хэш берется от пароля в чистом виде, то этот пароль можно подгадать по словарю. Случайная соль гарантирует, что по словарю этот секрет подобрать не удастся, а сгенерированный для одной соли словарь не подойдет для другой. В этом случае, конечно, предполагается что секрет у каждого клиента свой, иначе в случае подбора конкретного хэша есть риск, что там совпадет не только хэш, но и исходные данные, и тогда секрет будет известен атакующему
- Ресурсы, затрачиваемые хэш-функцией на создание хэша зависят от длины входной последовательности. Искусственно увеличивая входную последовательность, защищающийся повышает стоимость подбора совпадений для атакующего, потому что из-за маловероятности подбора коллизии случайным образом атакующий будет пробовать подобрать хэш, используя соль.

Comment: И всё же я не понял, зачем соль приписали в явном виде к токену. Чтобы хакер зря словари не пробовал проверять?)