# Как передавать id записи php (проблема безопасности данных)

Tags: php, ajax, безопасность, form, параметры

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему безопасности передачи параметра id для записи, которую я хочу изменить. На каком этапе возможно ошибка и почему так происходить

Есть журнал, в котором каждая строчка имеет свой id. При нажатии на строчку, открывается страница редактирования записи по этой строке журнала. 
открывается в виде с параметром $_GET /rec_update.php?id=12345

На странице редактирования есть форма в которой некоторое количество полей, например такая:

```
<form id="update_form">
<input type="text" id="rec_id" name="rec_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" id="creator" name="creator">
<input type="text" id="some_text" name="some_text">
</form>
```

отдельно есть кнопка:

```
<button type="button" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
```

в файле .js написан код, который будет обрабатывать нажатие на эту кнопку и с помощью jquery ajax записывать данные в базу:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_record.php",
    data: $( "#update_form" ).serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(save_status_code)
    {
        //здесь в зависимости от возвращённого кода save_record будут разные сообщения о сохранении или не сохранении записи.
    }
 });
```

И вот мы подошли к вопросу, как защитить базу и этот весь процесс от такого момента: я могу спокойно открыть через браузер - Инспектировать элемент - и изменить значение input value rec_id на то, которое мне захочется и это значение передасться в файл save_record.php как id записи в которую мы будем записывать изменения. Как на протяжении всего этого процесса действительно сохранить и не дать никакой возможности пользователю изменить этот ID? чтобы тот ID который я вписал в /rec_update.php?id=12345 таким же и дошёл до файла save_record.php ??

Comment: ну надо чтоб пользователь мог работать только с теми записями, на которые имеет право, в ином случае при проверке на серваке сказать - чувак, ты не прав, это не твоя запись, нефиг тут копошиться.

Comment: Проводить проверку на возможность изменения тех или иных видео-файлов для данного пользователя. На пример предоставить возможность редактирования только автору или другим группам пользователей, которые сами определите.

Comment: и эти проверки я так понимаю имеют смысл только непосредственно в файле save_record? куда мы уже передали форму?

Comment: и да и нет. как вариант можно но только вкупе с проверкой *ДО*.... ....... так что проще будет проверку на право редактирования делать *ДО* вывода формы и в случае её не прохождения делать ата-та, в теории позволяя в итоге редактировать запись только разрешённым лицам...... а редактирования можно логировать, чтоб если что можно было отследить виновника беспорядков

Comment: но ведь проверки JavaScript можно попросту отключить - они ведь на стороне пользователя работают - так ведь?

Comment: @VladimirMedinsky критичные проверки делаются на сервере.

Answer (score 2):

Берете из журнала поля редактируемой записи в том числе и id. Собираете их в одну строку. **Добавляете соль.** Хешируете все алгоритмом sha1, sha256 или sha512. И полученный хэш вставляете в форму в скрытое поле.

При получение данных от пользователя повторяете операции с получением хеша и сверяете его с пришедшим хешем из формы. При совпадении - записываете данные, при не совпадении - выдаете ошибку.

Comment: это так можно сразу послать в соседнюю тему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651614/191482  чтоб ознакомился и подписался на неё)

Comment: Посылайте, я же не против :Р

Comment: попробую, возможно это и будет решением проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, перед редактированием чего-то, пользователь заходит на страницу - грубо говоря, к примеру /products/111/edit. Вот перед выводом этой вьюшки и делается проверка на доступ пользователя к этой записи, плюс непосредственно перед сохранением на той странице/действии, чтобы нельзя было послать сфабрикованный POST запрос.